# Android app stops responding after closing telnet window in PC

Tags: java, android, telnet, serversocket

I tried to write a simple server for an app that user can write a message from PC using telnet to IP and port. IT works just fine and it can show the

The problem is, when user closes telnet window (CMD window in PC, there is where user connects to app) the app stops.

Is there a way to prevent this behaviour? Here is my code:

```
//Defined in Activity class 
//Sockets, servers, clients and stuff    
public java.net.ServerSocket MyServerSocket;
public String IpAddress = "";
public int Port = 12345;
public Handler UpdateConversationHandler;
public Thread ServerThread = null;
```

Nested classes inside the Activity class:

```
class ServerThread implements Runnable{

    public final String IpAddress;
    public final int Port;

    public ServerThread(String ipAddress, int port)
    {
        IpAddress = ipAddress;
        Port = port;
    }

    public void run() {
        Socket socket = null;

        try{
            MyServerSocket = new ServerSocket(Port);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        while(!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()){
            try{
                socket = MyServerSocket.accept();
                CommunicationThread commThread = new CommunicationThread(socket);
                new Thread(commThread).start();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}

class CommunicationThread implements Runnable
{
    private Socket clientSocket;
    private BufferedReader input;

    public CommunicationThread(Socket clientSocket)
    {
        this.clientSocket = clientSocket;

        try{
            this.input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(this.clientSocket.getInputStream()));
        } catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void run() {
        while(!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()){
            try{
                String read = input.readLine();
                UpdateConversationHandler.post(new UpdateUIThread(read));
            } catch (IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}

class UpdateUIThread implements Runnable {

    private String msg;

    public UpdateUIThread(String str) {
        this.msg = str;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        _textview_info.setText("Client Says: "+ msg );

    }
}
```

I also have this code for `onStop` method, but it doesn't help!

```
@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();

    //Closing server socket
    try
    {
        MyServerSocket.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

And this is the onCreate method, where the server starts:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    _context = this;

    //Prepare spinners
    _preferences = getSharedPreferences("org.pervasivesystems.nexusmosaic", MODE_PRIVATE);
    _preferencesEditor = _preferences.edit();
    _spinner_videos = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_select_video);
    _spinner_ids = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_select_id);
    populateSpinners();

    //Prepare server
    IpAddress = getIpAddress();
    TextView tvIpAddress = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview_ip_address_value);
    tvIpAddress.setText(IpAddress);
    _textview_info = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview_information);
    UpdateConversationHandler = new Handler();
    ServerThread = new Thread(new ServerThread(IpAddress, Port));
    this.ServerThread.start();
}
```

**UPDATE**

When I start the app, even before connecting from PC to app using telnet, I get the following message continuesly in LOGCAT:

```
11-14 15:45:32.460    W/System.err? at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
11-14 15:45:32.460    W/System.err? java.net.SocketException: Socket is closed
11-14 15:45:32.460    W/System.err? at java.net.ServerSocket.checkOpen(ServerSocket.java:362)
11-14 15:45:32.460     W/System.err? at java.net.ServerSocket.accept(ServerSocket.java:120)
11-14 15:45:32.460    W/System.err? at .MainActivity$ServerThread.run(MainActivity.java:233)
```

Line 233 is refering to this code:

```
    while(!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()){
        try{
            socket = MyServerSocket.accept(); //LINE 233
            CommunicationThread commThread = new CommunicationThread(socket);
            new Thread(commThread).start();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

I also found out that after closing the telnet window from PC, the `UpdateUiThread` keeps running.

Comment: Its hard to tell from the code you put up. Why dont you put up some of the actual activity code so we can see how your activity life cycle plays out.

Comment: If you mean onResume or etc, actually I havent implement any lifecycle yet to my app. everything is just default, OnCreate and OnStop are the only methods I have overwriten

Comment: You might be doing something like incessantly updating the UI thread with null strings after the connection closes at the PC end.

Comment: @Jamesandresakis ok just did, pls have a look

Comment: When you say the user closes the telnet window how are they doing that? are they pressing back or home?

Comment: NO! the telnet window is on windows PC , and I mean they just close the window by cliking the X

Comment: Are you getting any log cat errors or messages/warnings?

Comment: @Jamesandresakis Check my latest edit pls, I do get error even before connecting from Telnet

Comment: Your error before connecting might be an error in opening the socket, for example if that port was recently used and you did not apply the equivalents of SO_REUSEADDR and related.

Comment: Why dont you try checking if the socket is closed in your while loop or while condition.

Answer (score 0):

What is probably happening is that your communication thread is noticing the terminated connection and exits.  This is how you wrote it.  Im not sure what you want it to do instead...

If you want to do something after the terminated connection, just put some code right after

```
while(!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()){  ...  }
```

Wait for the thread to finish, then do what you want.

Sometimes it helps me to add some system outs throughout threaded code to get a handle of when things are firing off/ending.  It will help, trust me.

Comment: Thanks for info I am tying this and also adding some log to LOGCAT to see if I can catch something

Comment: I found out that after closing the telnet window from PC, the `UpdateUiThread` keeps runing.

Answer (score -2):

Try this

```
do{
    if(!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()){
        try{

            socket = MyServerSocket.accept();

            if(socket!=null && socket.isConnected()){
                CommunicationThread commThread = new CommunicationThread(socket);
                new Thread(commThread).start();
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
  }while(socket!=null && socket.isConnected());
```

Comment: This causes app to stop on start because `socket.isConnected()` throws nullreference

Comment: try null checking your socket and then if its not null try using isConnected. If that doesnt work then you may want to try using a do loop instead of a while.

Comment: Yeah did that but still stops on closing telnet window

Comment: did you try something like the change I made above